# Numbered references Elsevier style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have to make my references on `model1-num-names.bst`,
when I compile the main file (.tex), references appear correctly on my paper like [1]..[12] and so on.
but in the reference section, references appear without the itemlist (bibitem), and number of pages on each reference doesn't match the real one.
example:
my main file

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}   
%% The `ecrc' package must be called to make the CRC functionality available
\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,colorlinks=true} 
\begin{}
....
....
....
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{references}
\end{}
```

after compilation, references appear directly like this:

```
References
    A.Padmanabhan,  S.Ghosh,  and  S.Wang  (2010).A  self-organized grouping sog framework   for efficient grid resource discovery.J Grid Computing, 8:365–38.
```

where I want it to appear like:

```
References
    [1] A.Padmanabhan,  S.Ghosh,  and  S.Wang  (2010).A  self-organized grouping sog framework for efficient grid resource discovery.J Grid Computing, 8:365–389.
```

here is an example of my (.bib) file for the above reference:

```
@article{PGW-2010,
 Author =    {A.Padmanabhan and S.Ghosh and S.Wang},
  Journal =  {J Grid Computing},
  Pages =    {365-389},
  Publisher =    {Springer},
  Title  =   {A  Self-Organized grouping SOG framework for efficient grid resource discovery},
  Volume =   8,
  Year =     2010
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Could you produce a *complete* (i. e. with  preamble) minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: i've edited my question, knowing that I've resolved the first issue, but the problem of number of pages remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, it was the fault of my use of the apalike package `\usepackage{apalike}`, once I've removed it, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @article{PGW-2010,
  author =    {A.Padmanabhan and S.Ghosh and S.Wang},
  journal =  {J Grid Computing},
  pages =    {365-389},
  publisher =    {Springer},
  title  =   {A  Self-Organized grouping SOG framework for efficient grid resource discovery},
  volume =   8,
  year =     2010
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{PGW-2010}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but my references are in another separated file (references.bib)? may be I did not understand you. but I would like to keep my references databases separated from my main file. thank you.

Comment: now, i've another problem, I do not know if i have to post it in a new question.
it doesn't display the correct number of pages of it each reference after compilation: ex: it shows: 365-38 rather than 365-389.